# How can I exclude an App (camera) from the recent Apps list?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, recents-screen

How to exclude camera from recent App list? (long-press Home Key in Galaxy S 2)

I don't want it to appear in the Recent app list since it has traces/image of last captured image.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove it from the list by just swiping it off. I don't know how to permanently remove it from the list, though.

Answer (score 3):

Judging from the fact that you are seeing previews of recent apps, I'm assuming your SGS2 is running Android 4.0 (or ablove).  I don't believe you can exclude apps from "recent" list out of the box.

This might be one of the few legitimate uses for the Task Killer kinds of apps.  Basically if you set the task killer to always terminate the "Camera" or "Gallery" apps, they should stop appearing in Android's recent apps list.*

***[Correction]**:  The above statement turned out to be incorrect on Jelly Bean (Android 4.1).  Task-ending an app does not remove it from the "Recent" list.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I always thought the "recent" refers to "recently used" -- not to "currently running in background". As far as I remember it also held apps which were for sure cleared away by the OOM Killer. Or does that depend on the Android version?

Comment: @Izzy Not 100% sure, but I will try to test this out on my Galaxy Nexus running 4.1 (Jelly Bean).  Will update my answer with results.

Comment: OK -- I'm curious as for the results. BTW: IMHO Task killers should only be applied against misbehaving apps (i.e. those hogging CPU or other ressources and won't quit), that is, in exceptional cases.

Comment: @Izzy Couldn't agree more on task killers.

Comment: I was wrong. Task-killing an app does not remove it from the recent list. I will edit my answer accordingly. However, the Camera app does not display the preview on 4.1 Android version. Gallery still does though.

Comment: Thanks for checking, @Chahk -- so I can stop being confused. Already thought they might have changed something ;) Time to get myself something with at least ICS on it xD Btw: You still forgot to correct your answer -- it still says killing should get them off that list...

Comment: Finally got to a real computer.  Trying to edit posts on a mobile is a pain.

Comment: So.. they is no way out for this...

Answer (score 2):

I just tested it while writhing those steps and it's working if your phone is rooted.
If you need a method without root, Just ask me and I will try to do some test.

1. Download Tasker and open it then go in the preferences and uncheck the beginner mode.
2. Go back in Tasker and open the "Profile" tab then click on the + symbol.
3. If Tasker ask for a name, give it a name like "launch camera" and click on the check, Then click on the + symbol and choose "Application".
4. Choose the camera.
5. Use the top left arrow to go back.
6. Select "New Task"
7. If it ask you for a name give it a name like Launch Camera.
8. Click on the + symbol and type "kill" then select "Kill App" and select the Camera.
9. Check "Use root"
10. Use the top left arrow to go back.
11. Click on the + symbol and select "App" then "Launch App" and select the camera.
12. Check exclude from recent apps and then use the top left arrow to go back.
13. Use the top left arrow to go back one more time.
14. click on the 3 dots at the top right of the screen and select "Exit" then select "Save First"
15. Launch your camera app and see if it's working.

Comment: Welcome to the site. This is good work. You don't need to edit your instructions into a different answer as well as posting your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tasker! When you launch an app with tasker, you can specify to exclude the app from the recent apps.

You could create a button that launch the camera app in excluded mode.

Comment: Tasker is not a simple to use app for beginners. It would help if you could give step-by-step directions on how to accomplish this with Tasker.