# Prevent Trebuchet from showing up in Recent Apps?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, home-screen, trebuchet

Here's the setup I have for my phone right now:

- I am running on a custom ROM that has Trebuchet for the home application.
- The custom ROM is ICS-based.
- I have somewhat successfully gotten Google Now (the Jelly Bean feature) to work on my phone.
- I decided to use [Home2 Shortcut](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eikatou0.appspot.home2shortcut&hl=en) to map double-clicking on my home button to launch Google Now's voice input.

The above setup works fine aside from a single caveat. When I view the Recent Apps menu while inside another application, I can see Trebuchet on the list. This is not the behavior I was looking for and from what I can tell, it is appearing on the Recent Apps because I've set Home2 Shortcut as my new home app (to handle the double-clicks) and then Home2 Shortcut opens Trebuchet as regular application.

So yeah, now I want to know how I can make Trebuchet **not** appear on Recent Apps. Is there some kind of manifest-editing that I can do to make Trebuchet act that way? If not, what other approaches can I try?

Comment: Duplicate? http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27963/how-can-i-exclude-an-app-camera-from-the-recent-apps-list?rq=1

Comment: Umm I think mine is a different case.

Comment: Trebuchet is CM's own version of the stock ICS launcher, have you not tried the CyanogenMod forums about this issue?

Comment: I don't think my ROM is pure CM though. It's a cross between AOKP and CM I believe.